# postfix won't start. libnss_dns-2.13.so

Tags: postfix-mta

My personal server crashed (hdd issue) and had to restore backup. 
everything is working except for postfix that gives that error when trying to start:

```
Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent: postfixtar: 
lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_dns-2.13.so: No se puede open: El fichero ya existe

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

"No se puede open: El fichero ya existe" is spanish for can't be opened, file already exists.